# VLOOKUP/ MATCH INDEX not working when the lookup value is from a dropdown

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In column 'C' there are employee names and some blanks that will later have names assigned. In column 'J' there are the corresponding employees ID numbers. In column 'J' I have a MATCH/INDEX formula so that when an employees name is entered in column 'C', the other cell is also populated with the employees ID.

This was working fine until I added data validation in the form of a dependent drop down in column 'C'. After that the MATCH/INDEX works fine if you type in a value, but it returns the error #N/A if you use the drop down to select a value. I then tried using VLOOKUP but that also has the same results.

Does anybody know what I can do to solve this. So that when value from the drop down is selected the INDEX/MATCH works, without having to type it?

All this formatting is also achieved through a macro (Not sure if that makes a difference).

Heres the forumla currently in column 'J'..

```
=INDEX('Employee Details'!L:L,MATCH(C6,'Employee Details'!M:M,0))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would check your data type before and after adding the validation. Is it text ? Is it numeric ? If its working when you enter it manually, I would suspect your dropdown is pulling text values but your data lookup is numeric.

Comment: You're probably trying to do something like matching a string to a number

Comment: You're right it does appear that they are different data types, selecting from the drop down isn't resulting in a text data type. Is there anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Had to retype the name values which my drop downs were referencing. Although they looked the same they were somehow different to the list of name values I was using in the INDEX/MATCH formula. After this it all worked.